# Is it an error to have more than one primary key table constraint?

Tags: sql

I have a question about the primary key table constraint.

Is it an error to have more than one primary key table constraint in one table definition?

```
create table "entity" (
  "id1" integer,
  "id2" integer,
  primary key ("id1"),
  primary key ("id2")
);
```

The [SQL BNF](https://ronsavage.github.io/SQL/sql-2003-2.bnf.html#table%20element%20list) defines the `<table element list>` as a list of `<column definiton>`s or `<table constraint definition>`s. This does not put a limit on the number of `primary key` statements per table. So the question is: is there anywhere else in the non-free SQL standard a limitation of primary key statements defined?

Or is the semantic meaning of the above definition equivalent to a combined primary key?

```
create table "entity" (
  "id1" integer,
  "id2" integer,
  primary key ("id1", "id2")
);
```

**Update:**

It seems that no RDBMS supported by [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) allows the first example, although the BNF allows it.

Sqlite says:

> Error: table "entity" has more than one primary key

PostgreSQL says:

> ERROR: multiple primary keys for table "entity" are not allowed

Oracle says:

> ORA-02260: table can have only one primary key

MS SQL says:

> Cannot add multiple PRIMARY KEY constraints to table 'entity'.

MySQL is not standard compliant at all. So it does not count.

Comment: The only bad thing to have more than one PK, on `sub selects` cannot return unique value (can trick with `concat`)

Comment: It is not an arror to have more than one, PK, it is forbidden, and thus impossible. Having more than one UNIQUE constraint is possible, though. And, yes, it is perfectly legal to have a composite PK. [BTW: the "only one PRIMARY KEY" constraint is a *semantic* constraint, I would not be surprised if the syntax *per se* would allow it.]

Comment: run each command and see what happens.

Comment: @DanBracuk You would have to provide a truly SQL standard compliant SQL server first, though. We are not talking about MySQL or SQL Server or Oracle, we are talking about the SQL Standard.

Comment: @Alexander: the supplied SQL in the question **is** standard SQL (except for the invalid definition of two PKs in the first statement).

Comment: @Valijon: I assume you mean a multi-column PK, not multiple primary keys (because that's not possible). And you can absolutely return unique values from a sub-query with a multi-column PK: `where (a,b) in (select c,d from ...)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Then please give me a standard compliant SQL server against which I may "run each command  and see what happens". Every SQL server I know accepts non-standard queries, and may even reject standard-compliant queries, so "run each command and see what happens" does not tell us anything about the standard.

Comment: @Alexander the question is about DDL, not about queries. DDL's define or impose a *model*, queries only try to do useful things within that model.

Comment: @joop Can you quote the semantic constrain from the standard? I would accept that as an answer.

Comment: The syntax you linked to is not the standard, it is *part* of the standard. And, looking at it, it is **syntactically** legal to have a `create table t(a integer, a integer);` Or even: `create table t(a integer primary key, a integer primary key);`. The syntax allows it, the constraints (column names must be unique within a table, there is only one PK) are *semantic*

Comment: @joop Yes you said this already. But you are not the standard. I would happily accept this answer, if you can give me a quote from the standard. Without the quote it is just your opinion.

Comment: @ceving If what you're looking for isn't real-life use but a quote from the standard, please edit your question to make it clear that it is indeed your point...and it will probably then be closed as offtopic (asking for an off-site resource).

Comment: @JiriTousek LOL: everything on this site is an off-site resource. Stackoverflow did not invent programming.

Answer (score 4):

A table can only have one `primary key`, that's why it is called "primary" (note that this one key can be composite, i.e. based on multiple columns).

Some databases allow you to add additional [alternate / candidate keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key#Alternate_key). Most allow you to define a column or set of columns as `unique`, which in effect is the same as having an alternate key.

Comment: The question is not, if it is allowed to have more than one primary key. I know that a table can have just one primary key. The question is, if it is allowed to have two `primary key` statements.

Comment: @ceving well if what you're looking for is a statement in official ANSI SQL2003 standard saying it's not allowed, I recommend you buy the access to the standard and look it up, it could be described in feature ID `E141-03`. Since the standard isn't free I guess it might even be illegal to quote from it here.

Basing your doubt on the BNF seems a bit irrational to me, since BNF cannot describe that constraint (only one `PRIMARY KEY` constraint) well, and we all agree (it seems) that defining two primary keys would not make any sense in real use.

Comment: The problem is, that I have just the BNF and for me it would be reasonable to define a combined primary key with two primary key statements. But for the majority of vendors it is not reasonable. BTW it would of course be possible to write a BNF where only one primary key statement per table is allowed.

Comment: @ceving, there is no such thing as a primary key statement in the ANSI/ISO SQL standard.

Comment: @ceving possible, yes, but quite a pain since the ordering of clauses is arbitrary.

Comment: @jarlh [unique constrain definition](http://savage.net.au/SQL/sql-2003-2.bnf.html#unique%20constraint%20definition)

Comment: @ceving, I know about constraints, but there's no primary key STATEMENT.

Comment: @jarlh Thanks for spitting my hair.